# Can i use Same google maps api key for 2 different applications?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation

So i am working on an taxi application (like uber) on android studio java. However the clients want there to be 2 different applications one for the driver and one for the client. So i can use google maps i need to  get a google api key. But how will i be able to link the google map of the client to the one for the driver so that a driver can know where the client is and client knows where the driver is simultaneously . Should i use the same api key for both applications does that work since they share the same database and server? Otherwise how will be able to link both?

Ive already built both applications separately and linked them to the same database (im yet to link them to the server i intend to use)

Comment: "link the google map of the client to the one for the driver so that a driver can know where the client is and client knows where the driver is simultaneously".  That has nothing to do with the google map API key.  The API key is used to determine the developer of the app so they can be charged.  It doesn't share data between clients of the same API key.  That kind of functionality is 100% on you to write.

Comment: @GabeSechan in that case it does not matter whether the api key is shared amongst both applications what matters is how i implement the functionality in the code?

Comment: Yes.  It's been a while, but IIRC you just have to use the Google Maps developer page to tell it the package name of all your apps that will share the key.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [API best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#separate-apikey), It is recommended that you use separate ones for security reasons but while one API key per application is ideal for security purposes, you can use restricted keys on multiple apps as long as they use the same type of application restriction.

Now with regards to your plan on reproducing an uber like app with navigation and other stuff from Google Maps API by combining them together to create such an app, I'd suggest that you seek legal advise and review the Google Maps Terms of Service [3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services. (d) No Re-Creating Google Products or Features](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#:%7E:text=Customer%20will%20not%20use,for%20Android%20mobile%20app.):

> *Customer will not use the Services to create a product or service with features that are **substantially similar to or that re-create the features of another Google product or service**...*

The reason I'd suggest that you review the Terms is because Google Maps API already have the **[On-demand Rides and Deliveries Solution](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/transportation-logistics/on-demand-rides-deliveries-solution)**

As per the documentation:

> *The On-demand Rides and Deliveries Solution is a development toolkit for building on-demand mobility services. You can use the Navigation SDK alone to provide real time tracking maps in your app. If you want to add coordinated trips, the toolkit provides web services and a set of APIs that wrap the functionality of maps, routes, and places into interfaces specifically designed for ridesharing and delivery solutions.*

You can read the documentation to learn more about it. But with this, I believe this fits with your use case and for you to start availing for this is for you to [Contact Sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact-maps?_gl=1*12gyyoy*_ga*MTc0Njc1MzI3OC4xNjk4OTc1OTY0*_ga_NRWSTWS78N*MTY5ODk3NTk2NC4xLjEuMTY5ODk3NjA5MS4wLjAuMA..) first since **this is currently available only to select partners.**

I hope this information helps!